# Better to use "less than equal" or "in" in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

If i have to update more than 10000 rows in the table, and the table contains more than 700000 records and the rows we have to update their primary key are in continuous manner.
Is better to get max primary key and then use "less than equal" in sql query or i have to use in query?

Comment: It depends on which 10000 rows need to be updated. Your specs aren't clear.

Comment: its hard to tell it could be starting 10000 rows or middle or can be last...

Comment: There is no such thing as 'middle 10000 rows' if you don't want to use the id or any other field to sort by. A database might (theoretically) return the records in a different order each time. Never rely on the given order, unless you explicitly order by certain fields or specify a range.

Answer (score 1):

The best will be to use `between`

Say you want to update the table's column1 whose entity_id(PK) is in a range of 10 and 10000.

```
update table set column1=somevalue where id between 10 and 10000
```

Using `in` clause will require to either get the id's from a sub query or you need to put in the braces

Comment: i have all the Ids and don't want to put in the In statement

Comment: Then you can use any logical operator say <> or you can use between if the id's are in a range, I was giving you an option

Comment: i just want query that will take minimum time of execution.

Comment: please paste the explain plan, of your query

Comment: If you want the fastest query possible, maybe you shouldn't be picky on what not to use. Using an id to identify a record is not too bad. That's why they call it an id...

Comment: update tableName set enumValue='1', dateModified=now() where ...... after that i have to use condition

Comment: *`"after that i have to use condition"`*, which is `where id between 10 and 10000`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since they're identical, there's really no distinction in terms of speed or anything else. better to use  more natural to you.

You can use simply **less than or equal**

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name=value WHERE row_id <= 10000
```

One thing to be careful of, is if you are using this against a DATETIME, the match for the end date will be the beginning of the day:

<= 6/12/2012 is not the same as: <= 6/12/2012 23:59:59 (**it would match against <= 6/12/2012 00:00:00.000**)