# Why is hash index slower using "Less than" in SQL

Tags: sql-server, indexing, hash, binary-search-tree

I've finished my first semester in a college-level SQL course where we used "SQL queries for Mere Mortals" 3rd edition.

Long term I want to work in data governance or as a data scientist, so digging deeper is needed and I found the Stanford SQL course. Today taking the first mini quiz, I got the answers right but on these two I'm not understanding WHY I got the answers right.

My 'SQL for Mere Mortals' book doesn't even cover hash or tree-based indexes so I've been searching online for them.

I mostly guessed based on what she said but it feels more like luck than "I solidly understand why". So I've ordered "Introduction to Algorithms" 3rd edition by Thomas Cormen and it arrived last week but it will take me a while to read through all 1,229 pages.

Found that book in this other stackoverflow link =>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66515417/why-is-hash-function-fast

Stanford Course => https://www.edx.org/course/databases-5-sql

I thought a hash index on College.enrollment would not speed up because they limit it to less than a number vs an actual number ?? I'm guessing per this link [Better to use "less than equal" or "in" in sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738426/better-to-use-less-than-equal-or-in-in-sql-query) that the query would be faster if we used "<=" rather than "<" ?
[image]

This one was just a process of elimination as it mentions the first item after the WHERE clause, but then was confusing as it mentions the last part of Apply.cName = College.cName.
[image]

My questions:

1. I'm guessing that similar to algebra having numerators and denominators, quotients, and many other terms that specifically describe part of an equation using technical terms. How would you use technical terms to describe why these answers are correct.
2. On the second question, why is the first part of the second line referenced and the last part of the same line referenced as the answers. Why didn't they pick the first part of each of the last part of each?

For context, most of my SQL queries are written for PostgreSQL now within PyCharm on python but I do a lot of practice using the PgAgmin4 or MySqlWorkbench desktop platforms.

I welcome any recommendations you have on paper books or pdf's that have step-by-step tutorials as many, many websites have holes or reference technical details that are confusing.

Thanks

Comment: "My 'SQL for Mere Mortals' book doesn't even cover hash or tree-based indexes" - I suspect that's because SQL is ostensibly a high-level language for expressing a query in terms of _what the result should be_ instead of _how to get the results_ - that's why there's nothing in "standard" SQL for expressing exactly what algorithm should be used to perform a JOIN, because that's the RDBMS' concern, not yours.

Comment: The best answer for question 2 depends on the `STATISTICS` (and cardinality) of the tables - do you know any information about the cardinality of those tables?

Comment: I'm disappointed the teaching-material is using old-style (as in **obsolete for 30 years already, jeez**-old) `JOIN` syntax. Ugh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. A hash index is only useful for equality matches, whereas a tree index can be used for inequality (`<` or `>=` etc).**

With this in mind, `College.enrollment < 5000` cannot use a hash index, as it is an inequality. All other options are exact equality matches.

This is why most RDBMSs only let you create tree-based indexes.

---

**2. This one is pretty much up in the air.**

*"the first item after the WHERE clause"* is not relevant. **Most RDBMSs will reorder the joins and filters as they see fit** in order to match indexes and table statistics.

**I note that the query as given is poorly written.** It should use proper `JOIN` syntax, which is much clearer, and has been in use for 30 years already.

```sql
SELECT *   -- you should really specify exact columns
FROM Student AS s    -- use aliases
JOIN [Apply] AS a ON a.sID = s.sID   -- Apply is a reserved keyword in many RDBMS
JOIN College AS c ON c.cName = a.aName
WHERE s.GPA > 1.5 AND c.cName < 'Cornell';
```

Now it's hard to say what a compiler would do here. A lot depends on the cardinalities (size of tables) in absolute terms and relative to each other, as well as the data skew in `s.GPA` and `c.cName`.

It also depends on whether secondary key (or indeed `INCLUDE`) columns are added, this is clearly not being considered.

**Given the options for indexes you have above, and no other indexes (not realistic obviously), we could guesstimate:**

- `Student.sID, College.cName`
  This may result in an efficient backwards scan on `College` starting from `'Cornell'`, but `Apply` would need to be joined with a hash or a naive nested loop (scanning the index each time).
  The index on `Student` would mean an efficient nested loop with an index seek.
- `Student.sID, Student.GPA`
  Is this one index or two? If it's two separate indexes, the second will be used, and the first is obviously going to be useless. `Apply` and `College` will still need heavy joins.
- `Apply.cName, College.cName`
  This would probably get you a merge-join on those two columns, but `Student` would need a big join.
- `Apply.sID, Student.GPA`
  `Student` could be efficiently scanned from `1.5`, and `Apply` could be seeked, but `College` requires a big join.

Of these options, the first or the last is probably better, but it's very hard to say without further info.

**In a real system,** I would have indexes on *all* tables, and use `INCLUDE` columns wisely in order to avoid key-lookups. You would want to try to get a better feel for which tables are the ones that need to be filtered early etc.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but I understand that inequalities can use hash-indexes if their domain is specific (or selective?) enough: e.g. bit or enum columns.

Comment: Perhaps, and in the case of enums you would still have to limit it to one possible value, but I'm not aware of any RDBMS that does so

Answer (score 1):

#### First question

[A hash-index is not linearly-searchable](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eparis/cs564-f15/lectures/lecture-11.pdf) (see Slide 7), *that is*, you cannot perform range-comparisons with a hash-index. This is because (in general terms) hash functions are one-way: given the output of a hash function you cannot determine the input, and the output will be in *apparently* random order (having a random order is good for ensuring an even load over the set of hashtable bins).

Now, for a contrived and oversimplified example:

Supposing you have these rows:

```
PK | Enrollment
----------------
 1 |          1
 2 |         10
 3 |        100
 4 |       1000
 5 |      10000
```

A perfect hash index of this table would look something like this:

Assuming that the hash of `1` is `0xF822AA896F34253E` and the hash of `10` is `0xB383A8BBDAA41F98`, and so on...

```
EnrollmentHash     | PhysicalRowPointer
---------------------------------------
0xF822AA896F34253E |                  1
0xB383A8BBDAA41F98 |                  2
0xA60DCD4E78869C9C |                  3
0x49B0AF769E6B1EB3 |                  4
0x724FD1728666B90B |                  5
```

So given this hashtable index, looking at the hashes you cannot determine which hash represents larger enrollment values vs. smaller values. But a hashtable index does give you `O(1)` lookup for single specific values, which is why it works best for discrete, non-continuous, data values, especially columns used in `JOIN` criteria.

Whereas a tree-hash does preserve relative ordering information about values, but with `O( log n )` lookup time.

#### Second question

First, I need to rewrite the query to use modern `JOIN` syntax. The old style (using commas) has been obsolete since SQL-92 in 1992, that's almost 30 years ago.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Apply
    INNER JOIN Student ON Student.sID = Apply.sID
    INNER JOIN College ON Apply.cName = Apply.cName
WHERE
    Student.GPA > 1.5
    AND
    College.cName < 'Cornell'
```

Now, generally speaking the best way to answer this kind of question would be to know what the `STATISTICS` (cardinality, value distribution, etc) of the tables are. But without that I can still make some guesses.

I assume that `College` is the smallest table (~500 rows?), `Student` will have maybe 1-2m rows, and assuming every Student makes 4-5 applications then the `Apply` table will have ~5m rows.

...armed with that inference, we can deduce:

- `Student.sID = Apply.sID` is an ID match - so a hash-index would be better in most cases (excepting if the PK clustering matters, but I won't digress).
- `Student.GPA > 1.5` - this is a range search so having a tree-based index here helps.
- `College.cName < 'Cornell'` - again, this is a range comparison so a tree-based index here helps too.

So the *best* indexes would be `Student.GPA` and `College.cName`, but that isn't an option - so let's see what the benefits of each option are...

(As I was writing this, I saw that @charlieface posted their answer which already covers this, so I'll just link to theirs to save my time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67829326/159145 )